# How to obtain the set of all signals for a given widget?

Tags: pyqt5, qt5, pyside2, signals-slots, qobject

I am looking through the Qt documentation. Is there a quick and dirty way to get a list of all signals that a widget can emit.

For example (withPyQt):

```
allSignalsList = thisWidget.getSignals()
```

Alternatively, is there is a nice place on the new Qt5 API that shows all the signals for a given QObject?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's no built-in method for listing signals, but normal python object introspection will get the information fairly easily:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

def get_signals(source):
    cls = source if isinstance(source, type) else type(source)
    signal = type(QtCore.pyqtSignal())
    for subcls in cls.mro():
        clsname = f'{subcls.__module__}.{subcls.__name__}'
        for key, value in sorted(vars(subcls).items()):
            if isinstance(value, signal):
                print(f'{key} [{clsname}]')

get_signals(QtWidgets.QPushButton)
```

Output:

```
clicked [PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAbstractButton]
pressed [PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAbstractButton]
released [PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAbstractButton]
toggled [PyQt5.QtWidgets.QAbstractButton]
customContextMenuRequested [PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget]
windowIconChanged [PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget]
windowIconTextChanged [PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget]
windowTitleChanged [PyQt5.QtWidgets.QWidget]
destroyed [PyQt5.QtCore.QObject]
objectNameChanged [PyQt5.QtCore.QObject]
```

However, it's probably better to learn to use the [Qt Documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/classes.html). If you go to the page for a Qt class, there's a **Contents** sidebar on the top-right which has links for the main member types. This usually includes a section for signals, but if it doesn't, you can drill down through the inherited classes until you find one.

So for example, the [QPushButton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpushbutton.html) page doesn't show a signals section, but it inherits [QAbstractButton](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html), which does [have one](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#signals).

Comment: So for the classes that don't show signals on the 'contents' sidebar, you must look at the class from which it inherits. I see. Also, nice, instructive code snippet.

Comment: Is there a safe way to detect and skip all signals originating from the QObject base?

Comment: @Silicomancer I updated the code example so that it breaks it down by class. Hopefully you can see how to adapt that to your own use-case.

Answer (score 7):

The trick is to use the QObject's [meta object](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html) to iterate through the QObject's methods, then pick out the ones that have a signal type.

For example, this code snippet will print out the names of QThread's signals:

```
QThread thread;
QMetaObject metaObject = thread.staticMetaObject;
for (int i = 0; i < metaObject.methodCount(); i++) {
    QMetaMethod method = metaObject.method(i);
    if (method.methodType() == QMetaMethod::Signal) {
        qDebug() << "Signal: " << method.name();
    }
}
```

It should be trivial to adapt that to put the QMetaMethods into a QList or any other data structure.